# Libreoffice Base Crashing

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Libreoffice ver. 5.3.4

Libreoffice work correctly before and after I update to version 16.04.
Since a Software update, Base start crashing, was advised to install LO version 5.3.4 which I did
now Base and Writer they crash suddenly on startup only Calc and Impress work.
I was advised to change the kernel to version 4.4.0-79 my kernel is now 4.4.0-81.
Should I change the kernel?
Libreoffice Base crashing is a known bug with Ubuntu, I am writing in LO Writer on my 
other Hard Disk Drive with Ubuntu 16.04 OS the kernel 4.10.0.27 LO and other applications work correctly I thick this was the kernel on my main disk before the Software update.
The makers of Ubuntu should know about this bug why don’t they make a fix.
Is there any one can help to fix I this need LO working properly urgently.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If crash at open LO, go to this path `~/.config/libreoffice/4/` and take backup from `user` folder then remove it(`user` folder).

```
$cd ~/.config/libreoffice/4/
$cp -r user user_backup
$rm -r user
```

open LO again.